Setting x-axis data in data visualization using matplotlib is not working properly
I'm using a CSV file and want to put the date data as it appears in the table directly on the x-axis of the graph, but the x-axis data in my graph is displayed incorrectly. Which part of my code could be wrong?
I have attached the table and the resulting graph as URL.

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

def get_font_family():
    import platform
    system_name = platform.system()

    if system_name == "Darwin":
        font_family = "AppleGothic"
    elif system_name == "Windows":
        font_family = "Malgun Gothic"   
    
    return font_family

plt.rc("font", family=get_font_family())

df_price_index = pd.read_csv("/Users/sun/Downloads/품목별_소비자물가지수_품목성질별_2020100__20240626234308.csv", encoding='cp949')

df_price = df_price_index[df_price_index["품목별"] == "총지수"].copy() # 총지수 품목만 추출하여 복사본 생성

df_price["전년동월대비"] = df_price["데이터"].pct_change(periods=12) * 100 # 전년 동월 대비 증감률 계산

# print(df_price.dropna()) # 결측값 제거 후 데이터 출력 

df_price_notnan = df_price.dropna()

print(df_price_notnan)

plt.figure(figsize=(10,4))

plt.plot(df_price_notnan['시점'], df_price_notnan['전년동월대비'], marker=".")

I'm a beginner, so I'm not sure which part is wrong.

What do you mean by "the x-axis is displayed incorrectly" ? It seems like you gave df_price_notnan['시점'] for the x values in plot.plot(...), and from your screenshot the 시점 column ranges from 2023.05 to 2024.05 as your x-axis in the plot.

From what you write it seems you want the column '시점' to be interpreted as dates, whereas in your chart it is interpreted as floats.
There are 2 ways to fix this issue, either you read the data already as a date or you later transform your column to a datetype.
See this answer if you want to transform your dates already when loading.
To transform your data after it was read in:
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# sample data where 'Date' is of type float
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': [2023.01, 2023.02, 2023.03, 2023.04, 2023.05, 2023.06, 2024.01],
                   'Value': [1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 0, 1]})
# transforming 'Date' from float via string to datetime format
df_corrected = pd.to_datetime(a['Date'].astype('string'), format='%Y.%m') 

The detour via astype('string') was necessary, because the floats would be interpreted as a timestamp and yield dates in the year 1970.
